# Is there a SWT widget to display DFX/Autocad Files? (or a converter to convert it to Draw2D)

Tags: java, swt, autocad, draw2d, dxf

I have some DXF or Autocad files, and need those to display in a eclipse rcp application. Is there a widget which provides such functionality? Or is there a library to convert these somehow to draw2d objects?